# Print only unique array elements to file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am trying to write the output to a file. But when I write this code, it is writing the same line multiple times. How can i stop repeating the same line multiple times?

Java_location is my output.

Here is my code:

```
a = []
a << java_location
File.open("/home/weblogic/javafoundmodified.txt", 'w+') do |file|
  a.each { |item| file.puts item }
end
```

My output i am getting now is:

```
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java
1.7.0_65/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_65/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_65/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: Does `a` always have one element?

Comment: Is `java_location` an array? If it is, you can write `a << java_location.uniq` instead of `a << java_location`

Comment: I guess we need to know if the content of `a` is different from the contents of `javafoundmodified.txt`

Comment: no a does not have element.

Comment: yes java_location is an array. The java_locations has these lines 1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java 1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java 1.7.0_65/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/jre/bin/java

Comment: the javafoundmodified.txt is the file which i am writing to am file.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. It should not return the result you claim. It is invalid Ruby code.

Comment: Where is `Java_location` used? Also, what is `java_location`?

Comment: Oh come on; edit the question--you can't believe anybody can read that comment?!

Comment: @DaveNewton, it's not so bad after running it through an Enigma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this (with example array in `javalocation`):

```
javalocation = %w|
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java
1.7.0_65/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_65/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_65/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/jre/bin/java
|

File.open("/home/weblogic/javafoundmodified.txt", 'w+') do |file|
  javalocation.uniq.each { |line| file.puts line }
end
```